# Prime Factor Random Numbers!

Tags: code-golf, random

#### Task:

Given two positive integers, generate a random integer between them (inclusive) and then output all its prime factors.

#### Examples:

```
Input:   Random Number:     Output:
1,2      2                  [2]
12,46    18                 [2,9]
142,17   40                 [2,2,2,5]
```

#### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the least bytes wins!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
Ÿ.RÒ
```

Explanation:

```
Ÿ       Create a list [a .. b]
 .R     Pick a random element
   Ò    Prime factors.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6A69oMOT/v83NOIyMfual6@bnJickQoA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s>  4 bytes

```
rXÆf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/78o4nBb2v///w2N/puYfc3L101OTM5IBQA)

**How it works**

```
rXÆf 
r     inclusive range
 X    random element's
  Æf  prime factorization
```

*-1 byte thanks to @LeakyNun*

Comment: 4 bytes: [`rXÆf`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/78o4nBb2v///w2N/puYfc3L101OTM5IBQA)

Comment: Thanks. I thought there would be a problem with range using the first argument and the output of `X` applied to the second argument.

Comment: The `21` rule only applies in monadic chains.

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 38 bytes

```
#&@@@FactorInteger@RandomInteger@{##}&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
PO}F
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=PO%7DF&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%2C2%0A12%2C46%0A142%2C17&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyffman 1](https://github.com/L3viathan/pyffman), <s>90</s> 80 bytes

This is a joke language that was published today (but before the challenge!). It is based on compressing Python using a pre-made Huffman code based on a corpus of golfed Python. Since the code doesn't really consist of bytes (it's bit-based, due to its huffmannness), I give you here the hexdump obtained using `xxd`.

```
00000000: 9c23 9c8f f5fe 9e1d 744a 4ac4 860f 2fcb  .#......tJJ.../.
00000010: 1218 3cbf 70d5 9577 b8cb 4059 44a4 2dbf  ..<.p..w..@YD.-.
00000020: fbaa 9763 4a75 bbbb 90e1 7ac8 410f fbba  ...cJu....z.A...
00000030: 0c91 a0d8 528d dde3 8fd9 0e19 0c56 2ca6  ....R........V,.
00000040: c699 893b 9e1b bc47 fb29 b1a6 624e 79e8  ...;...G.)..bNy.
```

(The original Python code this is based on is <s>164</s> 158 bytes.)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 79 bytes

```php
for($a=rand($argv[1],$argv[$i=2]);1<$a;)$a%$i?$i++:$a/=$i+!$r[]=$i;print_r($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJReZhutpKuko2RsDCRMlWKt/6flF2moJNoWJealaIBVRBvG6kAYKpm2RrGa1oY2KonWmiqJqiqZ9iqZ2tpWKon6tkCGokpRdCyQYV1QlJlXEg80pkjT@v//r3n5usmJyRmpAA)

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 5 bytes

```
SYrYf
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=SYrYf&inputs=%5B10+1%5D&version=20.1.1)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input as a 1 x 2 array
S       % Sort the input such that the lower end of the range comes first
Yr      % Generate a random integer in this range
Yf      % Compute it's prime factors
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 13 bytes

```
{$~),\,-mRmf}
```

Anonymous block that expects an array of two numbers in the stack and replaces it by an array with the output.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP2fU/e/WqVOUydGRzc3KDet9n9dwf9oEzMFQ6PYr3n5usmJyRmpAA)

#### Explanation

```
{       e# Begin block
  $     e# Sort array
  ~     e# Split into the two numbers, a and b, where b is greater
  )     e# Increment b
  ,     e# Range from 0 to b
  \     e# Swap
  ,     e# Range from 0 to a-1
  -     e# Set difference: range from a to b
  mR    e# Random choice
  mf    e# Array of prime factors
}       e# End block
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <strike>7</strike> 6 bytes

```
óV ö k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///DmMIXD2xSy//83NDHSUTA0/5qXr5ucmJyRCgA)

Explanation

```
oVÄ ö k
oVÄ        range of integers between first input and second input + 1
    ö      get a random item from the array
      k    return all prime factors
```

Saved a byte thanks to ETHproductions